# Xubuntu themes look ugly after hdmi cable is unplugged

Tags: hdmi, themes, xfce, xubuntu

I sometimes connect my laptop to an external monitor with an hdmi cable, and when I later unplug the cable, it causes a problem with the graphical theme in xubuntu (14.04). The window panes, panel, buttons etc look ugly, and I am unable to change the theme by going to Settings Manager -> Appearance -> Style (I mean the style is on Greybird, as it should be, but it doesn't change when I click on different styles). This only seems to happen sometimes after I unplug the hdmi cable (not every time).

Screenshot of ugly appearance

[image]

Screenshot of normal appearance

[image]

The only way I can fix it is to log out and back in again, after which the appearance is back to normal. I assume something is crashing (gtk?). Can anyone explain what might cause this, or how I could track down the cause?

Comment: I experience this on 14.10 when I also plug in the HDMI cable, not just unplug it.

ps: Thanks for deleting my "answer" @Mokubai, I was going to do that this morning after I realized it should have been a comment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need recompile xfce4-settings with this patch:

http://bug-attachment.xfce.org/attachment.cgi?id=5681

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nvidia-graphics-drivers-331/+bug/1308105

Comment: Please, instead of just posting a few links, include some information on how to solve the issue here, on the site. Thanks.